# App Service retrieve secret from Key vault with RBAC using Azure AD group

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-appservice, azure-rbac

We are setting up an Azure App Service (Web app) that needs to get some secrets from a Key vault. For this, we have enabled System assigned identity for the web app. The Key vault is using RBAC and we decided to create an Azure AD group to give access. We added a role assignment (Key Vault Secrets Officer) on the Key vault for the Azure AD group.

In the app service, I can go to "Identity" and press on the button for "Azure role assignments". Here I see the role assignment made:
[image]

However, if I go to Application settings, it says that it does not have access. I have given it about 3 hours, without success. I have restarted and updated other settings to trigger restart.

[image]

If I put myself to this Azure AD group I get access to go and work with secrets..
Any ideas why this is the case? Is this not supported for RBAC yet?

Thanks!

Comment: access denied is probably more related to networking. is there any firewall rules/vnet integration associated to this kv ?

Comment: Hi @Thomas! Unfortunately this is not caused by networking

Answer (score -1):

I see you have Azure key vault officer permission to the group .

> **NOTE:**
>
> 1. Please note that **azure AD Groups with Managed Identities may require
>    up to *`eight(8) hours`* to refresh tokens and become effective.**
> 2. ***The application also needs at least one Identity and Access
>    Management (IAM) role assigned*** to the key vault or else the access
>    policies to access .

- In case even if you have given a particular user individually , the
  RBAC permsission, Your app needs the proper access permssions to
  access keyvault. i.e;the managed identity has been generated but not
  granted access on key vault yet.  So, go to the key vault in Azure
  portal, which you need to be accessed by the required azure app
  service.
- You can check in the process of access permissions needed here in
  [create-and-assign-a-managed-identity in Azure web app  | Microsoft
  Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app#create-and-assign-a-managed-identity).

You can give RBAC to that Application /user/service principal or give access policies like below.

1. Under Settings in azure keyvault, select access policies option from left navigation and then click on Add access policy.

[image]

2. Here make sure to select atleast two permissions – ***Get and List*** – for **key** permissions, **secret** permissions and **certificate** permissions inputs which are least possible permissions to access keyvault by app service app.You can provide the other access permissions if needed.
3. Under Select principal, choose the None selected link to open the Principal selection pane. Enter the name of the ***user/group***, ***app*** or ***service principal*** in the search field, select the appropriate result, then choose Select.
   As you are using a managed identity for the app, select the name of the app in the app service itself by selecting add and then saving the changes.

[image]

If your vault is configured with [network restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview-vnet-service-endpoints), you must ensure the application has network access.

Please check this [***Assign an Azure Key Vault access policy*** (CLI) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-portal) for detailas.

- Then try to access after min 8hrs. If still there is access issue, it
  might be due to proper access policies not defined for that
  particular security group in step 3.
- Please check the same in the FAQ   [***How can I give the AD group
  access to the key vault?***   | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/troubleshooting-access-issues#how-can-i-give-the-ad-group-access-to-the-key-vault)

**References:**

1. [access-network-restricted-vaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#access-network-restricted-vaults)
2. [Using Azure RBAC with Azure Key Vault - Joonas W's blog](https://joonasw.net/view/using-azure-rbac-with-azure-key-vault)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the reply. As described, we do not want to use access policies, instead we want to use RBAC. 

Do you see any trouble in us giving RBAC access through an Azure AD group for managed identities? I can confirm that this is working just fine for a regular identity, but not from App Service system identity.

Comment: @mr3k, have you changed the setting for permission model on the Access policies tab to 'Azure role-based access control'

Comment: Also please check [this](https://www.seb8iaan.com/azure-ad-role-assignable-groups/) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67658341/key-vault-access-denied-in-azure-web-app-configuration-setting) , if you are missing any steps.

Comment: yes I have confirmed permission model as RBAC. Also the other links you sent. I can assign the web app's identity directly to the Key Vault for the role without problem, but when trying to inherit it through an Azure AD group it fails. Is this a limitation maybe?